# Why the animation does not change the text of the button to the next click?

Tags: java, android, objectanimator

When I press the first time the buttons go and come back with other
 letters, but when I press again nothing happens:
 `int d = -1;` `String btnanim = "0";`
 How to make it animated when I press the buttons again?

```
public void b_b1(View v) {
    if (this.btnanim == "AB") {
        btn("CD");
        return;
    }
    do {
        if (this.btnanim == "CD") {
            btn("EF");
            return;
        }
        if (this.btnanim == "EF") {
            btn("GH");
            return;
        }
    } while (this.btnanim != "1");
    btn("AB");
}
```

Without animation, the text changes

```
void btn(String str) {
    this.btnanim = str;
    this.timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        ObjectAnimator anim;
        LinearLayout bgroup = (LinearLayout) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.bg);
        Button b1 = (Button) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.b1);
        Button b2 = (Button) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.b2);

        public void run() {
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    MainActivity.this.d += 1;
                        switch (MainActivity.this.d) {
                            case 0:
                                anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(bgroup, "translationX", bgroup.getWidth() * 2);
                                anim.setDuration(500L).start();
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(bgroup, "translationX", -bgroup.getWidth() * 2);
                                anim.setDuration(0L).start();
                                anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(bgroup, "translationX", 0);
                                anim.setDuration(500L).start();
                                switch (MainActivity.this.btnanim) {
                                    case "AB":
                                        b1.setText("A");
                                        b2.setText("B");
                                        break;
                                    case "CD":
                                        b1.setText("C");
                                        b2.setText("D");
                                        break;
                                    case "EF":
//Do not repeat the animation this: Changes A and B to C and D then nothing

                                        b1.setText("E");
                                        b2.setText("F");
                                        break;
                                }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0L, 100L);
    }


    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        MainActivity.this.btnanim = "AB";
    }
}
```

Comment: You never seem to set `this.btnanim = "1"`. So `this.btnanim != "1"` is always true. Looks like you have an infinite loop there.

Comment: I cleaned do and while. For the first time animation is run. The letters on the buttons change. b1 = A-> C b2 = B-> D. I press once again for the b1 = C-> E, b2 = D-> F. But the animation does not move from place to place. I so understand it is necessary will put a cycle in a code but how and where.

Answer (score 0):

I added `this.d = -1;` in `void btn(String str) {}`

Now it works right!